# @reach/router - path updates but component doesn't render when Link clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, reach-router

I started using `@reach/router` for a new project based on a recommendation on the `react-router-dom` github page. Unfortunately, what seems like a very simple use case is not working. I began by trying to use the @mui `BottomNavigation` component with the `@reach/router` `Link` as follows:

```
<BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} component={Link} to="/favorites" />
```

Clicking on the button in the nav does update the URL in the browser, but it does not render the "favorites" component. So I removed a variable and tried routing directly between components:

```
<Link to="/favorites">Favorites</Link>
```

and that also failed in the same way, URL updates but the component does not render. I thought about using programmatic navigation with the `useNavigation` hook provided by `@reach/router` but that only works within a component that is nested under a `Router` parent, and my `BottomNavigation` component is not since it is not addressable via a path. Any thoughts on why this isn't working. Seems like a simple use case.

Here are the relevant details.

AppRoutes.tsx

```
<Router onChange={(event) => console.log(event)}>
   <LoginPage path="/" />
   <VisitedPage path="/visited" />
   <FavoritesPage path="/favorites" />
   <OptionsPage path="/options" />
   <HousePage path="/house" />
</Router>
```

BottomNav.tsx

```
<BottomNavigation
   showLabels
   value={value}
   onChange={(event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
   }}
>
   <BottomNavigationAction label="Visited" icon={<VisibilityIcon />} component={Link} to="/visited" />
   <BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} component={Link} to="/favorites" />
   <BottomNavigationAction label="Options" icon={<SettingsIcon />} component={Link} to="/options" />
</BottomNavigation>
```

App.tsx

```
<div>
   <Header />
   <div className="content">
      <AppRoutes />
   </div>
   <BottomNav />
</div>
```

Example of linking between components:

```
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from "@reach/router";

export default function OptionsPage(props: RouteComponentProps) {
    return <Link to="/favorites">Favorites</Link>
}
```

Comment: Hint: use useEffect hook

Comment: Why @reach/router? I have the same problem but I have to use @reach/router because it's already used in the system. If you are starting project from scratch why not use react router? @reach/router and react router merged into react router v6.
https://reach.tech/router/ 'Future' paragraph talks about that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by using:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';

render(<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

instead of:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to render app.

ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18 so I think you should just switch to react router. Alternatively you could use javascript instead of typescript as @react/reach works correctly on it.